# How can I generate a UUID from the command line in Windows XP?

Tags: windows-xp, command-line, uuid

How can I generate a UUID from the command line in Windows XP? Something like "uuid" or "uuidgen" in Linux.

Comment: cross-site duplicate: [Generate GUID in Windows with batch file](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4313422/995714)

Answer (score 33):

If powershell is installed this is a simple commandline to get a guid

```
powershell -Command "[guid]::NewGuid().ToString()"
```

Comment: You can make it a reusable command within PowerShell with. function uuid { [guid]::NewGuid().ToString() }.  Just run "uuid" as needed.

Comment: I put this line in guid.bat in a PATH folder so it works in regular command prompt and PowerShell.

Comment: for folks running this on `Git Bash`, stick this into a function in `.bashrc` as 
`function guid() {
  powershell -Command "[guid]::NewGuid().ToString()"
}`. Invoke it by just typing `guid` and hitting `Enter`.

Comment: Now even `powershell -command new-guid`, if I am may copy answer from mentioned cross-site dupclicate.

Answer (score 7):

Drop the following code into a new file name uuid.vbs

```
set obj = CreateObject("Scriptlet.TypeLib")
WScript.StdOut.WriteLine obj.GUID
```

Then you can run it from the command line like so:

```
cscript //NoLogo uuid.vbs
```

This will work on pretty much any computer that has the Windows Scripting Host installed - which certainly includes anything later than Windows 2000, and probably includes 95/98/ME as well... though I don't have an instance handy to check.

If you need to remove the braces, replace the last line with this

```
WScript.StdOut.WriteLine Replace(Replace(obj.GUID,"{",""),"}","")
```

Comment: Funny how in Windows it's only unique to each planet, but in Unix and related systems it's unique throughout the entire universe.

Answer (score 3):

You can also use this command in a command prompt: 
`wmic path win32_computersystemproduct get uuid`

Comment: seems like it's only good for 1 guid

Comment: This does NOT generate a GUID. It just shows an existing guid. DO NOT USE this if you want a unique GUID

Comment: Relevant XKCD: https://xkcd.com/221/

Answer (score 3):

Now in powershell, you can use built in `New-GUID` function:

```
For /f "tokens=* delims= " %%a in ('powershell -noP -c "& {(New-GUID).GUID}"') do set "GUID=%%~a"
```

Answer (score 2):

From MSDN Library: [Generating Interface UUIDs.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa373928%28VS.85%29.aspx)

Comment: Do you know where I can download this "uuidgen" from?

Comment: It comes with Visual Studio - I'd expect it to come with the express edition of Visual C++ which I believe is a free download, as well

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa373930%28VS.85%29.aspx says that the `uuidgen` utility (Uuidgen.exe) is automatically installed when you install the Platform Software Development Kit (SDK).

Comment: Is it not available as a seperate download, as I have no use for the SDK or for Visual Studio.

Comment: @Zubair: Install SDK, get uuidgen, uninstall SDK. Anything else is a copyright violation.

Comment: I tried installing the SDK on my Windows XP but it said it required the .NET framework to be installed. Is it possible to just find the uuidgen program, as installing .net might make other programs on my machine fail?

Comment: I don't think installing .NET will do harm to your programs.

Comment: Ok, thanks, I'll check that it is safe to install .net and if so I will do this

Comment: I installed everything with Microsoft SDK and it still didn't work

Answer (score 2):

To copy a new GUID to the clipboard, use this command :

```
cmd /c powershell.exe -Command "[guid]::NewGuid().ToString()|Set-Clipboard"
```

You can run the command straight from the Start, Run dialog ( WinLogo + R ), 
then use Ctrl+V to paste the generated GUID, which WILL also save it into your Run dialog history  - aka if you use it often it will pop-up as suggestion there ...

Answer (score 2):

I found that `uuidgen.exe` is present inside my `C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\bin\10.0.22621.0\x64` directory, probably because of some components that I have installed along with Visual Studio.

So I simply added `C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\bin\10.0.19041.0\x64` to my PATH and now it's easy to remember to type `uuidgen` like I'm used on macOS instead of having to remember a long command.

Answer (score 1):

If the system OS does not have Windows SDK but does have a C compiler with mingw-w64 toolchain then compile this small program to generate random GUID. Imported functions are [UuidCreate](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/rpcdce/nf-rpcdce-uuidcreate) (rpcrt4.lib) to create random UUID and [StringFromCLSID](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/combaseapi/nf-combaseapi-stringfromclsid) (ole32.lib) to convert UUID to wide string.

```c
#include <Windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>

/*
 * int UuidCreate(GUID *id);
 * int StringFromCLSID(GUID *id, wchar_t **str);
 * Libraries: Rpcrt4.lib Ole32.lib
 */

int main(void)
{
    GUID id;
    wchar_t *str = NULL;

    UuidCreate(&id);
    StringFromCLSID(&id, &str);
    wprintf(L"%ls\n", str);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [Windows Subsystem for Linux](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install), eg [install Ubuntu](https://ubuntu.com/wsl) -

```
Welcome to Ubuntu 22.04 LTS (GNU/Linux 5.10.16.3-microsoft-standard-WSL2 x86_64)

$ uuidgen
(prints a uuid)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  FOR /F %a IN ('POWERSHELL -COMMAND "$([guid]::NewGuid().ToString())"') DO ( SET NEWGUID=%a )
```